# Can I make Release description required?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to make Release description required when creating release?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid azure devops doesnot have an out of box option to make `Release description required`.

However, these is a workaround by using the [Invoke Rest Api Gate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#configure-a-gate) to check if  `Release description` is given before deploying the releases. Using Gates cannot prevent you from creating the release. It will only stop executing the deployment.

Check below detailed steps:

1, create a service connection to your azure devops organization.

Go Project Setting--> Service connections under Pipelines-->Click new service connection--> select Generic to create a generic service connection.

[image]

2,Then Edit the service connection type the information shown in below screenshot. Check here to get a Personal access token.

[image]

3, Go the your release definition edit page-->Pre-deployment conditions-->Enable Gates-->Add Invoke Rest Api

[image]

4, Edit the Invokde Rest API

Select the generic service connection to your azure devops created in the first step.

Set the fields as below:

- **URL suffix and parameters**: `/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=6.1-preview.8`
- **Success criteria**: `ne(root['description'],'')`

please check here for more information about [GET Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api.

See below screenshot:
[image]

When you create a release. The Gates will be evaluated and check if the release description is set. And will not execute the deployment if the Gate failed.

Comment: Where can I make it a feature request? :)

Comment: @PiotrPerak You can submit the feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21)

Comment: Created - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/1299524/make-it-possible-to-make-release-description-requi.html